# Issue getting xml with php

Tags: php

I'm using a php file to get some cross origin xml data. When the xml file contains 1 "message" , my php is rendering it "null" , but when the xml file contains 2 "message" it works fine

Here is php

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
ini_set('user_agent','mflscripts');

if($_GET["type"]=="chat") {
    //REQUIRED PARAMETERS
    if(!isset($_GET['server_id'])) { echo json_encode(array()); die(); } else $server_id = $_GET['server_id'];
    if(!isset($_GET['league_id'])) { echo json_encode(array()); die(); } else $league_id = $_GET['league_id'];
    if(!isset($_GET['year'])) { echo json_encode(array()); die(); } else $year = $_GET['year'];
    //OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
    if(!isset($_GET['cookie'])) $cookie = ''; else $cookie = $_GET['cookie'];
    if(!isset($_GET['random'])) $random = ''; else $random = $_GET['random'];

    $url = 'ht'.'tps://www'.$server_id.'.myfantasyleague.com/fflnetdynamic'.$year.'/'.$league_id.'_chat.xml?MFL_USER_ID='.$cookie.'&random='.$random;
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
          
    $json_xml = json_encode($xml);
    $json = json_decode($json_xml,TRUE);
    $my_json = array();
    $my_json['messages'] = array();
    $my_json['messages']['message'] = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($json['message']);$i++){
        $my_json['messages']['message'][$i] = $json['message'][$i]['@attributes'];
    }
    echo json_encode($my_json);
}
?>
```

When i read an xml file as follows

```
<messages>
<message message="asdf" franchise_id="0000" id="1661170418wng204" posted="Mon Aug 22 8:13:38 a.m. ET 2022"/>
</messages>
```

The php returns

```
{"messages":{"message":[null]}}
```

However when i read the xml file with multiple "message" it works correctly

```
<messages>
<message franchise_id="0000" id="1661174329csw208" posted="Mon Aug 22 9:18:49 a.m. ET 2022" message="asdf"/>
<message id="1661170418wng204" posted="Mon Aug 22 8:13:38 a.m. ET 2022" franchise_id="0000" message="asdf"/>
</messages>

php returns
{"messages":{"message":[{"franchise_id":"0000","id":"1661174329csw208","posted":"Mon Aug 22 9:18:49 a.m. ET 2022","message":"asdf"},{"id":"1661170418wng204","posted":"Mon Aug 22 8:13:38 a.m. ET 2022","franchise_id":"0000","message":"asdf"}]}}
```

So what am i doing wrong in the php to not get message retrieved when only 1 message exists ?

Comment: Have you checked what your `$json` variable contains/looks like when there's only one message, instead of only assuming it will have the same structure?

Comment: Have you checked what your `$json` contains? My guess would be, that `$json['message']` probably isn't actually an array, when your XML only contained one of those elements.

Comment: Here's the two versions for reference: https://3v4l.org/jW8I1T#v8.1.9

Comment: Can anyone post how I can fix this properly ? I’m not fluent on php at all and appreciate any help

Comment: Don't convert to JSON, loop over the XML elements returned by simplexml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you can just iterate over the nodes directly, there's no need for the JSON stuff which honestly does a lot of "magic" depending on how it gets used.

The below function iterates over XML from a string but it can easily be adapted to use a URL, too.

```php
function process_xml(string $xml_string) : array
{
    // Process XML
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
    
    // Return array
    $my_json['messages'] = [];

    // Iterate over nodes
    foreach($xml->children() as $message) {
        
        // Technically not needed
        $tmp = [];
        
        // Iterate over attributes
        foreach($message->attributes() as $name => $value) {
            $tmp[$name] = $value;
        }
        $my_json['messages'][] = $tmp;
    }
    
    return $my_json;
}
```

I decided to move the JSON encoding stuff to outside of the function just to keep it more pure, but you can do as you wish.

```php
$xml_string_1 = <<<EOT
<messages>
<message message="asdf" franchise_id="0000" id="1661170418wng204" posted="Mon Aug 22 8:13:38 a.m. ET 2022"/>
</messages>
EOT;

$xml_string_2 = <<<EOT
<messages>
<message franchise_id="0000" id="1661174329csw208" posted="Mon Aug 22 9:18:49 a.m. ET 2022" message="asdf"/>
<message id="1661170418wng204" posted="Mon Aug 22 8:13:38 a.m. ET 2022" franchise_id="0000" message="asdf"/>
</messages>
EOT;

echo json_encode(process_xml($xml_string_1));
echo PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(process_xml($xml_string_2));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ifZcb#v8.1.9

**Edit**

Here's a version that should work with the URLs:

```php
function process_xml_url(string $url) : array
{
    // Process XML
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    
    // Return array
    $my_json['messages'] = [];

    // Iterate over nodes
    foreach($xml->children() as $message) {
        
        // Technically not needed
        $tmp = [];
        
        // Iterate over attributes
        foreach($message->attributes() as $name => $value) {
            $tmp[$name] = $value;
        }
        $my_json['messages'][] = $tmp;
    }
    
    return $my_json;
}
```

Comment: can you edit your answer to display my existng php file , i tried to insert what you had and got nothing but errors , thanks

Comment: Those are your provided XML files direct from the question. I don't have access to the query string parameters to access the provided URLs. But you can change the function simply by passing the URL into the function and calling `simplexml_load_file`: `$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);`. If you do receive any error message, please always post what they literally say. I've updated the question with a version that should support a URL.

Comment: That site exists to run PHP code in isolation and doesn't support 3rd-party code, nor does it support query strings or POST data. As such, it cannot load XML remotely. I just put my code there as a proof-of-concept. You will need to take the code I provided, bring it local, and merge into your code.

Comment: thanks , i finally got it , appreciate your help here